# (How much) does a functor preserve the covering relation?

Tags: category-theory

For want of a better word (is there one?) a "snug" functor is one that preserves the covering relation in the domain category. (e.g. the covering relation of a partially ordered set is the binary relation which holds between comparable elements that are immediate neighbours.) That is, neighbours in the domain category map to neighbours in the codomain.

Intuitively, any such functor must be full and faithful (?), but two fully faithful functors nonetheless differ in "snugness".

Perhaps there is a metric for how snug a functor is?
Perhaps their is an ordering of functors by snugness?

(The term "snug" functor is not good, because it has another meaning [here](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Etl/cambridge_bmc/cambridge_bmc_talk.pdf).)

Comment: What is "the covering relation"?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Perhaps it has a different name in general categories, but it is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_relation).

Comment: That gives a definition for posets only. I don't see any useful way of generalizing this definition to categories. Do you have a definition for arbitrary categories in mind?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm new to category theory and was hoping there would be a standard generalization. Perhaps I should have asked this (implicit) question first. It would appear easy to define for general preorders, but I don't know in general.

Comment: I would generalize it like: arrow $f$ is a covering whenever $f=gh$ implies $g$ or $h$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: FYI Tom Leinster has used the term "snug functor" to mean [something else](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/cambridge_bmc/). It's not that widely-used, but it's out there.

Comment: @tcamps Thanks. I will update the question (not sure I understand what exactly what Tom Leinster means yet).

Comment: @Berci I have mentioned your idea [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3909507/how-can-the-covering-relation-of-a-partial-order-be-generalized-to-arbitrary-c?noredirect=1#comment8062958_3909507).