# (How) can the covering relation of a partial order be generalized to arbitrary category?

Tags: category-theory, relations

This seems challenging because of the apparent non-transitivity of the covering relation (defined below) which would violate the category axioms.

@Berci suggests [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3905638/how-much-does-a-functor-preserve-the-covering-relation?noredirect=1#comment8062092_3905638) that one potential generalization is to call arrow   covering whenever =ℎ implies  or ℎ is an isomorphism. But I would need more explication to understand this possibility (and to extend it to a property of the entire category).

If this question has an answer, I believe that it offers another way to express how "veridical" a functor is, beyond its fullness of faithfulness, as suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3905638/how-much-does-a-functor-preserve-the-covering-relation?noredirect=1#comment8062092_3905638)

#### Defn: The covering relation (from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_relation)).

Let $X$ be a set with a partial order $\le$.
As usual, let $<$ be the relation on $X$ such that $x<y$ if and only if $x\le y$ and $x\neq y$.

Let $x$ and $y$ be elements of $X$.

Then $y$ '''covers''' $x$, written $x\lessdot y$,
if $x<y$ and there is no element $z$ such that $x<z<y$. Equivalently, $y$ covers $x$ if the interval $[x,y]$ is the two-element set $\{x,y\}$.

When $x\lessdot y$, it is said that $y$ is a cover of $x$. Some authors also use the term cover to denote any such pair $(x,y)$ in the covering relation.

Comment: Obviously, you could take the preorder associated to the category, and then the order associated to that preorder, but I'm not sure that's what you're looking for...

Comment: @FiMePr Thanks. If I understand, 1) you skeletalize (is there a conventional term?) the category, yeilding a preorder, and then 2) you construct a partial order on the quotient set of the equivalence, S / ~, the set of all equivalence classes of ~."

Comment: If by "skeletalize", you mean, "simplify" the class of morphisms, by collapsing all the arrows that have the same source and target into a unique morphism, then yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: @FiMePr Thanks, I meant "thin", i.e. make a thin category.